# Regex for {!Customobject_relateobject.name}

Tags: regex, salesforce

I don't know regex can you please help me to get regex for 
{!Customobject_relateobject.name}
String "Customobject_relateobject.name" can contain only "_" and "." in middle of word not even in first or last
"{!" and "}" is mandatory

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps, [`\{![^{}]*}`](https://regex101.com/r/qV6kK5/1) should suffice?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have to prevent "Customobject_relateobject.name" for space and any special character except "_" and "."  but your regex is taking special character too

Comment: Then, I guess you are looking for [`\{![a-zA-Z0-9_.]*}`](https://regex101.com/r/qV6kK5/2)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\{![a-zA-Z0-9_.]*}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qV6kK5/2)

The regex means:

- `\{!` - matches `{!` literally
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*` - 0 or more (due to `*`) characters that are lower- or uppercase Latin letters, digits from 0 to 9, underscore or dot
- `}` - literal `}`.

Answer (score 0):

`{!^[a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z0-9._]*[a-zA-Z0-9]?$}` if empty strings like {!} are not allowed and only latin and digits should be inside the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

I guess the word can't end with '.' or '_'  or have any digit in it. So this regex will give you what you want:

```
\{!(([a-zA-Z]+(_|\.)?)+[a-zA-Z]+)\}
```

If you want digits have this regex:

```
\{!(([a-zA-Z0-9]+(_|\.)?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}
```

Don't use the '\w' because it match the '_', and you can end with two together.